# How do I append dataframes/ lenghts of dataframe to a list in a loop in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Okay so i have a list of dataframes.

1. Df1_results
2. Df2_results
3. Df3_results

I want to know what dataframes has the most columns and how many columns that is.

So my plan to figure this out was to create a list of lenght of all dataframes then scan list for largest value.

So i wanted a list like size = [ 5, 4, 7]

```
print('This length')
print(len(df2_results))
```

I get length 4

```
size=[]
for i in range(2):    
    print('this is ')
    print("df" + str(i+1) + "_results")
    size.append(len("df" + str(i+1) + "_results"))
size # the list with the new items.
print('*************')
print(size)
print(max(size))
```

Here i get the length of the string which is 11. Ha. 
What is a better way to do this? How do I append the dataframes to  alist in a loop? How can i get the length of that dataframe when its in a loop?

Later on i might have 10 dataframes .SO i do not want to say say df1_results. i want to be able to say df+i+ _results.

Comment: `[df.shape[1] for df in [Df1_results, Df2_results,...]]`?

Answer (score 0):

Let Data_list be the list of DataFrames:

```
Data_list=[Df1_results,Df2_results,Df3_results,...]
[len(data) for data in Data_list]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If i do not want to put the 1 or 2 or 3. Right i want those in a loop. bc lets say i hvae 60 dataframes. i don't want to list all the dataframes . how would i do that.

Comment: Updated my answer